# Content Type Instantiation: Picking value of a reference field

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying sensenet features, my focus is on reference field inside content type.

I defined & installed the following content type successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentType name="EmployeeCT" parentType="GenericContent"handler="SenseNet.ContentRepository.GenericContent" xmlns="http://schemas.sensenet.com/SenseNet/ContentRepository/ContentTypeDefinition">
<DisplayName>Employee Record</DisplayName>
<Description></Description>
<Icon>Content</Icon>
<AllowIncrementalNaming>true</AllowIncrementalNaming>
<AllowedChildTypes>EmployeeCT</AllowedChildTypes>
<Fields>
<Field name="Manager" type="Reference">
  <DisplayName>Manager</DisplayName>
  <Description></Description>
  <Configuration>
    <AllowMultiple>false</AllowMultiple>
    <AllowedTypes>
      <Type>EmployeeCT</Type>
    </AllowedTypes>
    <SelectionRoot>
      <Path>/Root</Path>
    </SelectionRoot>
    <!--<DefaultValue>/Root/Path1,/Root/Path2</DefaultValue>-->
    <ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly>
    <Compulsory>false</Compulsory>
    <VisibleBrowse>Show</VisibleBrowse>
    <VisibleEdit>Show</VisibleEdit>
    <VisibleNew>Show</VisibleNew>
  </Configuration>
</Field>
</Fields>
</ContentType>
```

The problem is that I could not found & pick manager of employee.

Any help please,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any previously saved content with the type EmployeeCT? Because you set it as the only allowed type as the value of the Manager field.

I've checked your code on my local site and it works. First I had to save an Employee Record to create a content for a manager and then I was able to pick it as a manager of a new Employee Record.